# I have a problem installing Packet Tracer in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

Hi guys i need some help to fix this problem in packet tracer in my Ubuntu 20.04

```
gp@gp-GL552VX:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  packettracer
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 249903 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing packettracer (7.3.1) ...
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-3) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...

gp@gp-GL552VX:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package packettracer.
(Reading database ... 246567 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking packettracer (7.3.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on dialog; however:
  Package dialog is not installed.
 packettracer depends on libgl1-mesa-glx; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-3) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packettracer
gp@gp-GL552VX:~/Downloads$
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ6jN.png)

Comment: The error clearly states you're missing a dependency. Try this: `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx`, then try to install the packet tracer again.

Answer (score 4):

Install the missing dependencies (`dialog` and `libgl1-mesa-glx`):

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx dialog
```

Or use `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Hi I'm having a problem again regarding installing: sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx dialog